# How can I plug my portable generator into a "wall outlet"?

Tags: generator

Ok, before everyone starts immediately telling me "NO" let me explain.  I bought a new house last year and the original owner had installed a brown wall outlet in the garage.  Now, there are also 2 brown outlets in the house.  They are different than every other outlet in the house and according to the home inspector have no power that goes to them.  1 of the outlets is behind the fridge and the other is in the hall.  According to the directions in the garage the brown outlet in the garage is where you plug in a generator and it feeds power to the otherwise "dead" outlets indoors.  My problem is how do you plug the generator into the wall outlet?  Can you buy a power cord with 2 male ends?  Also where would I even go to get it?  There is no risk of "backfeeding" because these outlets are not wired into the rest of the home wiring.

Comment: People will still immediately tell you "no" because a cord with 2 make ends is exceptionally dangerous. If the owners intended these outlets to be used this way they should have provided a proper plug to plug into the generator. With the generator outside, not inside the garage.

Comment: @doxylover has it on this one, the safest way would be to hook it up with a male / plug then use a male female to hook up to the generator, if you do not have the correct cord you can make one with SO cord of the proper gauge for the amperage. DoxyLover you should post this as an answer.+

Comment: Making the cord may be needed for a 20a outlet. I hate it when I hit enter in comments for a carriage feed then run out of time to finish the comment.

Comment: Ed, when I mistakenly hit 'Enter' I just immediately go to 'edit' and finish. If I run out of time, I copy what I have typed in using *ctrl Insert* then I delete the original comment and put what I want into a new comment box using *Shift Insert*.

Comment: But before you do anything else,  buzz out the brown outlets to verify that they are connected to each other (and that hot <--> hot), and properly grounded, **and** not connected to anything else that the inspector might have missed.

Comment: @Johnny is correct, a suicide cord with 2 male ends **should not exist** -- because it could be erroneously plugged into any receptacle, and at that point *backfeed*, lighting up the entire house and the electrician fixing the wires.  Those guys are supposed to use grounding clamps, but I have found those to be *not 100%*.

Answer (score 12):

You should replace the garage outlet with an inlet, such as [this (Amazon, as an example)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002XDQAA6).

[image]

This way, you can use a standard male-female cord, either a standard extension cord or one made with the correct gauge of SO cord [Thanks, @EdBeal]. You avoid using a male-male cord which is so dangerous.

Comment: +1 But note @Johnny s comment about the danger of running a generator in a garage. Put it outside and connect it with a standard heavy duty extension cord .

Comment: **YES.  This is exactly the thing for that.** In fact, nothing keeps you from using a common (heavy) extension cord to jump this inlet to a nearby outlet (perhaps one on a dedicated circuit), leaving the brown outlets energized 24x7.  This configuration would be foolproof. (though perhaps not code legal).  @bib The outlet, er, wrongly-pinned inlet, is exactly where it should be - indoors. Since the use of a cord is assumed, nothing here implies OP means to run a generator indoors.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct solution. A male to male electrical cord is a really bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason the owner did this is because if he has a male plug inside, how does he plug an appliance into it? I think he has a double male plug from his generator to an outside dummy socket. Then that socket is connected to an inside dummy socket. It must be for hurricanes in order to not take cords through windows. This is potentially dangerous since you have a male end with power that can touch you when you're handling it or some other conductive material. I wouldn't recommend it. That male socket in the pic would be perfect in this case if its the one outside. No danger since it's a dummy and the only way to power it is to have it covered.The male to male plugs are called widow makers.